# Run time of reversing the words in a string

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

Let's say we were tasked with reversing the words in a string.

So if we had:

**Mary had a little lamb**

We'd get:

***yram dah a elttil bmal***

---

The implemented algorithm was the following:

```
string wordsToSplit = "Mary had a little lamb";

string[] words = wordsToSplit.split(" ");
string wordsReversed = "";

foreach( string word in words ) 
{
      string reversedWord = "";
      foreach( char letter in word ){
          reversedWord = letter + reversedWord;
      }
      wordsReversed += " " + reversedWord;
}
```

This psuedo code should work. However what is the run time of this particular algorithm? I thought it would've been O(n^2), where N is the number of words in the string. But that doesn't seem right...

Something tells me this is actually O(N) * O(M), where 'N' is the number of words and 'M' is the number of characters in each word. So in worst case scenario, this could be O(n^2), if we had something like "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p"...

What do you think? This is bugging me...

Comment: In your code, you never use "currentIndex".

Comment: `yarm` is incorrect.

Comment: `(number of words) * (number of characters in each word) == (number of characters in the string)`. You can't get less than that because you need to at least read the entire string. There is no squared anything anywhere in that formula.

Comment: Code edited for corrections.

Answer (score 2):

The actual time complexity depends on how string concatenation is implemented in your language. For example, in Java, a naive string concatenation in a loop will take O(N*M) time, where N is the total string length, and M is the number of string being appended.

In a reasonable concatenation algorithm (such as with Java's StringBuilder; see [Dynamic Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)), a self-growing buffer is used internally, in a way that guarantees linear time for a series of concatenations.

Anyway, in your case there's no need for dynamic buffers - you know in advance the length of the strings you build. You can even treat the input as a char array, and do the work in-place.

Answer (score 0):

In your algorithm:

- `split` has linear complexity in the length of the input string
- Assuming that by

  ```
  string wordsReversed;
  ```

  you actually meant

  ```
  string wordsReversed = "";
  ```

  and that by

  ```
  wordsReversed.join(" ", reversedWord);
  ```

  you actually meant

  ```
  wordsReversed += " " + reversedWord;
  ```

  then the body of the outer `foreach` loop has linear complexity in the length of `word` since both the inner `foreach` loop and the concatenation of `reversedWord` with `wordsReversed` have linear complexity in the length of `word`.
- Finally, the sum of the lengths of all the `word`s in `words` is the length of the initial input string

Therefore your total complexity is O(n), as it should be.

Also, "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p" is not a worst case scenario for this algorithm, for the reasons mentioned above, although the algorithm would indeed be somewhat inefficient in that case.